# Difference between with and apply functions in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and just started learning it. I came across `with` and `apply` functions in Kotlin. I just want to understand the difference between them in the below scenario:

I have a class `Person` and I assigning values to the properties of its object like this:

```
val andre = Person().apply {
    name = "Andre"
    company = "Viacom"
    hobby = "losing in ping pong"
}
```

But this can be done using the `with` function as well:

```
val andre = Person()
with(andre){
    name = "Andre"
    company = "Viacom"
    hobby = "losing in ping pong"
}
```

Now what is the difference between `with` and `apply` functions in this context ?

Comment: There is a useful comparison table here: https://proandroiddev.com/the-difference-between-kotlins-functions-let-apply-with-run-and-else-ca51a4c696b8.

Comment: The closest analogue of `with` is `let`, not `apply`. In your case there's very little difference between `let` and `apply` because you know the target is non-null.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, It's more like `run` (the extension method version). Both use a receiver and return the block's return value. `let` doesn't use a receiver.

Comment: @chris True, `let` converts the receiver to the lambda argument.